# Return a List of type that is given as parameter to a method?

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a method that will execute a query and return a Set of object of specific type. The type is given as param to method as follow:

```
Set<Person> people = Dao.executeQuery("select * from PERSON",Person.class);
```

In Dao class I would like to define the method as follow:

```
public static Set<???> executeQuery(String sql, ????){}
```

Can you please help me on how to write executeQuery method?

Comment: What persistence technology are you using? JDBC, Hibernate, JPA, JDO etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static <T> Set<T> executeQuery(String sql, Class<T> klass) {

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you can specify that T extend a class or implement an interface to restrict it a bit in the first bit where T is defined. `public static <T extends Something>`

Comment: Thank you. I was doing `public static Set<T> executeQuery(String sql, Class<T> c)` and I was getting error at <T>. Now it is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static <T> Set<T> executeQuery( String sql, Class<T> type );
```